# Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 9 upgrade and String[]

Tags: java, tomcat

We have a legacy application build in Java Struts framework. it's working absolutely fine up till tomcat 8 now for some reason we are supposed to move to Tomcat 9 but when we are deploying the same application to tomcat-9, form data is not bringing the form fields which are of type String[]. we are having null for these values.

**one scenario is:** we have a screen where user can select multiple values using checkbox every checkbox has a specific id attached when selected but when deploying this code to tomcat-9 its bring checkbox value as null.

any advice, please.

Comment: Any error in tomcat log?

Comment: no, it's not showing any error, it just not bringing the value of that checkbox as it's defined as String[] on the backend in the form as we expect multiple values in it.

Comment: On what JDK did you run Tomcat 8? Tomcat 9 requires Java 8. May be is an incompatibility of the Struts version with Java8